# Changing the "ft_min_word_length" in mysql config

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql version 5.5.The table which i am using for querying is in MyISSAM engine type, so the default "ft_min_word_len=4", i want to set it to 3. Is there any other method than changing the default "ft_min_word_len" in config file.